# Backup entire azure subscription using ARM templates

Tags: azure

I'm still quite new to Azure so bare with me if this doesn't make any sense, however I'm looking to backup every component of my Azure subscription using ARM Templates and store them in a Git repository.

It seems like a logical thing to do since it will allow a recovery of the entire platform if something catastrophic happened. It's not a very big subscription either.

I can go into each individual component, for example a Virtual Network -> Export template, and save the 'Template' and 'Parameters', and then add these to my git repo manually under an appropriately named folder structure.

However is there a better / faster way to do this? What's the industry standard way of backing it all up as code?

Answer (score 1):

Ask your self a question, why do I need this? Because, If you have a small infrastructure I think you can easily recreate it, on the other hand, you can use IaC solutions for easy recreation of a much larger infrastructure. In this case, you can use any IaC solution, for instance, [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/), it's more likely standard now for cloud deployments.

For critical data, you can use internal or external backup services, in Azure you have [Recovery Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/).

Terraform allows you to create modules for code to be less heavy, also you can have multiple state files for a different group of resources, which gives you resistance against code failures, or if you need to make a single change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's because I've adopted the infrastructure from another person, therefore I want to preserve their deployments in case I do something to break it.
Since Azure offers ARM Templates, why not use their solution instead of using a 3rd party solution which requires extra time to learn as well? Unless the answer is that ARM Templates aren't very good at backing up multiple deployments and are only really good at doing one at a time

Comment: Terraform allows you to create modules for code to be less heavy, also you can have multiple state files for a different group of resources, which gives you resistance against code failures, or if you need to make a single change.

Comment: Let's say you have 100 VMs and you need to attach a new data disk to all of them, it would be a pain because you would need to make a change in every ARM. In Terraform you use modules, so you would need to change one line and it will affect all resources.

Comment: Ok thank you - I'll have to look into Terraform a little more and see if it's feasible to use in our environment